# How can I distribute integer array elements periodically [See image for example]

Tags: java, c#, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

It's a slot machine game. We already know the number of different outputs. But it needs to work on any kind of variations of that table, obviously.

So far, I have tried several naive approaches:

- Dumping all results in an array and try to distribute them by moving along the array.
- Tried to insert elements one by one, finding an empty and 'periodic' slot for each element.

[Output Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuKK0.png)

[Examples Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPx2T.png)

I use indexes of rows data to create and distribute array elements periodically.
(eg: first row corresponds to value 0, second row corresponds to value 1 and so on..)

So my output array will consist elements from 0 to 10 and the size will be 100 for provided table.

**EDIT: I have deleted the old code because I come up with an actual solution. Unfortunately I'm not sure if it is the correct/optimum way and has no idea how to check it.**

Here is my code: https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#ng5xi35uewbrgc40avciud

[Here are the sample result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4Zkh.png)

Can someone maybe check my code and verify that I have the correct result?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you want to chose randomly from an array given a chance, you could count up the total chance, generate a number 0-max, and then go through the array, subtracting the chance until it is <= zero at which point you stop.
If you want to remove it from the array, you reduce the chance by one and the max by one. When a chance hits zero, it will effectively be removed.

Comment: Why the java tag?

Comment: I have just added images. Sorry for inconvenience, fairly new to stackoverflow :| @PizzaProgrammer

Comment: I don't understand the question. So the output is probability periods? If you want to sort int array into period order, you need periods as input. Also, I don't understand how input int array can look like (is it array from 0 to constant, if not why?).

Comment: Let me explain the table image: If spin perc is 13, that result will be outputted 13 times before creating a new cycle

Answer (score 0):

So, you want a pool where each possibility happens a fixed amount of times, before refilling the pool.
What you can do is make an array of integers, each index corresponding to the result, and each value being the probability.
Then, you create an integer that stores the sum of all probabilities.
When you want an item, create a number between 1 and the sum of probabilities (inclusive). Go down the array, subtracting the probability from the random number. When it is <= 0, that is your random choice.
To remove from the pool, subtract 1 from the chance of what you landed on, and 1 from the sum. When the sum is zero, that means the pool is empty and can be refilled. Here is an example in c#:

```
class RandomPool {
    private int[] chances;
    public int Total {get; private set;} // total pooled items
    public readonly int Length;
    public int this[int i] {
        get => chances[i]; // get the chance at an index
        set {
            Total += value - chances[i]; // updates the total
            chances[i] = i; // sets the chance at an index
        }
    }
    public RandomPool(int length) {
        chances = new int[length];
        Length = length;
    }
    public int Get() {
        // creates a random number 1-total
        int rand = Random.Range(1, total + 1);
        int i = 0;
        // loops through the chances 
        while (true) {
            // decreases the random value by the change
            rand -= chances[i];
            // if it is <= 0
            if (rand <= 0)
                return i; // return the index of the chosen item
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
var pool = new RandomPool(3); // create the pool
pool[0] = 5; // assign the chances
pool[1] = 2;
pool[3] = 3;
while (pool.Total > 0) { // while there is something in the pool
    int x = pool.Get(); // get an item
    Console.WriteLine($"Randomly chose index: {p}"); // log the result
    pool[x]--; // remove one from the pool
}
```

When `pool.Total == 0` you can refill the pool. Also, I haven't tested this code, so there might be a few errors.

Comment: If you want to do it an easier way, you could just make a list with each possible output in it one time for every chance it has. Then just grab them at random indices, before reconstructing the list once empty.

Comment: I actually came across this answer in another blog post today, which you can find here: https://lootlocker.com/blog/random-with-weights

But there is a problem in this approach (I guess)

Which is, there is a possibility of having 2 same values in the same period

eg: let's say value 10 which has a probability of 5 in 100 can appear 2 times in the first 20 selection? Can we guarantee that it won't happen?

Comment: I don't understand? Are you saying you want one possibility to appear once per 20 choices, and others to appear x/100 times? You could use two pools, where the first one has the x/20 options, where you start from index 1, and then index zero can be the 20 - Total to bring the total to 20. Then, if you get 1+ you use that, but if you get zero you instead call the x/100 pool. @ahmetay

Comment: By value 10 I meant the last row in the example table which appears 5 times in 100 selections. My mistake. So you answer became pointless because of my mistake :( Still couldn't find a perfect solution. My unit tests are failing :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to get this.  I will start with the inspiration, and then add how to do it efficiently.

Imagine you have a series of alarm clocks in front of you.  5 of them go off 13x per day.  The rest go off 9, 8, 7, 6, and 5 times per day.  (I chose this example to match your output table image.)  Each starts a random point between when it last went off and when it next goes off.

The answer you want is the order in which they go off.  This order is periodic - it repeats every day.  They also go off in exactly the right proportions every day.  But the random start makes them go off randomly.

Now how do we figure this out efficiently?  The idea is to use a [PriorityQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) to track when each alarm clock goes off.  So we'll want something like a [Record](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/language/records.html)`(double priority, String result, double weight)` to put into our queue.  Our `result` field will be your string description, the `weight` will be your 13 or whatever, and using [Random](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) you'll start `priority` at `rand.nextDouble() / weight`.  The priority queue will compare based on `priority`.

And now the heart of the loop where you you populate your array will be:

```
QueueItem qi = queue.poll();
answer.add(qi.result);
queue.offer(QueueItem(qi.priority + 1/qi.weight, qi.result, qi.weight);
```

This makes each array item take time `O(log(queue.size()))` to produce. And you see that every `qi.weight` times `qi.result` comes up, the `priority` increases by 1.  (So it is periodic.)

Comment: I really appreciate you trying to explain it to me but unfortunately I couldn't understands it. It's partly due to Java vs C#. Can you please explain it once again maybe more C# friendly way? This is my last day to finish and submit this task but I still couldn't find the perfect solution :( @btilly

Comment: @ahmetay Sorry, I don't do homework.  I also don't program in C#.  So I can google for and come up with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.priorityqueue-2?view=net-7.0, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=net-7.0 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record.  But turning that into working code is another story.